# RxJava2 & Room: Stop emitting events on delete

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

I have this database

```
interface UserDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    fun insert(user : User)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    fun get(): Flowable<List<User>>

    @Query("DELETE FROM user")
    fun deleteAll()
}
```

Everytime a record is inserted, `get()` will be triggered automatically, as expected.

```
override fun getUsers() : Flowable<User> {

    return db.userDao().get()
}
```

How can I stop this from happening when `deleteAll()` is called?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47699390/drop-delete-trigger-for-room-database

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Single` instead of `Flowable`. Secondly you can use a flag in your `onNext()` method of the subscriber. Turn the flag off after first run. Even if it gets triggered no changes will occur to your core code in `onNext()`.